# Android handler threads

Tags: android

Can I create more than one handler object for a thread with looper? Suppose I created two new `Handler` objects `h1` and `h2` associated with the UIThread's `Looper`. `h1` is posting `Message` `m1` and `h2` is posting `m2` to the UIThread's `Looper`.does `h1.handleMessage()` and `h2.handleMessage()` process m1 and m2 respectively so that other UI related events such as touches are handled by their respective handlers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) is to create a Thread with its *own* Looper.

> Can I create more than one handler object for a thread with looper?

Yes, multiple Handlers can use the same Looper and [MessageQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html).

> so that other UI related events such as touches are handled by their respective handlers?

While I'm confused by what you're trying to ask here, I know that only the main Thread can access UI objects.

Comment: Just one question before I tell what I meant by my last statement.So does h1.handleMessage() only handles messages posted by h1 to the looper?

Comment: Correct, `h1` only handles Messages or Runnable intended for `h1`. I don't believe it has access to any Messages for `h2`.

Comment: I din't quite get what you mean by 'access to any messages for h2'.You mean h1.handleMessage() don't have any access to m2?And what I meant by `other UI related events such as touches are handled by their respective handlers` is, I'm thinking that any events such as  touches,clicks on the UI would put a message/runnable in the Looper and their respective handlers would handle those.This is just my speculation.Don't know how true it is

Comment: That's right, `h1` shouldn't receive `m2` only its own messages (like `m1`). But for your other question, I don't know how a touch becomes a MotionEvent. I do know that you can catch MotionEvents in listeners like `OnTouchListener` or in Views with `dispatchTouchEvent()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sam's answer doesnt get it.

The question is : If I have 2 or more handlers which is created in the same thread or with the same looper as a constructor parameter as the following code:

`Handler h1 = new Handler(Looper.mylooper())
{//override handleMessage, if receiving messageA then do actionA};`

`Handler h2 = new Handler(Looper.mylooper())
{//override handleMessage, if receiving messageA then do actionB}`

then I do this:`h2.sendMsg(messageA)`, which handler will handle the message?

**My answer is Handler h2, each message will be handled only once by a handler chosen by the `target`  attribute of the message, default is  who sends who handles**. In your question, `h1.handleMessage()` and `h2.handleMessage()` do process m1 and m2 respectively so that other UI related events such as touches are handled by their respective handlers.

We can dive deep into the source code of [Handler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/Handler.java#Handler.enqueueMessage%28android.os.MessageQueue%2Candroid.os.Message%2Clong%29), and find that all the `sendMessage` method will jump into the following:

```
  private boolean enqueueMessage(MessageQueue queue, Message msg, long uptimeMillis) {
    msg.target = this; // Note this!
    ...
    return queue.enqueueMessage(msg, uptimeMillis);
}
```

When this thread's `Looper` is going to take message out of the queue, it will dispatch the message according to `Message`'s attribute `target`:

```
  msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);//decides which handler to process. This code is in Looper.loop()
```

In general,  we'll receive messages in the same handler which we use to send messages